# R How can I combine the arguments of a function

Tags: r, function

I need to combine the arguments of a function. The first argument is the data.frame and the second one the column.name. Inside the function I want to combine them like data.frame$column.name , bellow a silly example to illustrate this:

```
table_function<-function(x,y){
    return(table(x$y))
}
table_function(mtcars,cyl)
```

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: So, what about the values of that column? Empty?

Comment: mtcars is an R built-in data set. 

# Loading
data(mtcars)

head(mtcars$cyl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
table_function<-function(x,y){
  return(table(x[y]))
}
table_function(mtcars,"cyl")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer TeeKea.
To be honest works perfectly in the example, but R understand in a different way mtcars$cyl and mtcars["cyl"]

```
head(mtcars$cyl)
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6

head(mtcars["cyl"])
              cyl
Mazda RX4           6
Mazda RX4 Wag       6
Datsun 710          4
Hornet 4 Drive      6
Hornet Sportabout   8
Valiant             6
```

And my fuction is something like this:

```
table_function<-function(x,y,z){
xxx<-tapply(rep(1, nrow(x)), list(x$y, x$z), sum, na.rm = T)
return(xxx)
}
table_function(mtcars,cyl,gear)
```

With your solution I have the following error:
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'